# MongoDb attribute with dot character

Tags: mongodb

in my mongo document I have some attribute (keys) that contain the dot character (.)
I have no idea why mongo allowed it in the first place, but now I want to clean them up. I have tried escaping it with . but didn't work. I also tried the UTF8 notation but didn't work also. Is there any way of removing the attribute withought actually deleting and recreating the document?

Here's an example of how the entry looks like in mongo shell

```
mydocument: {
    "some.field": 10,
}
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: ha, hmmm you could pull it out modify the parts and then just do a save() so that it overwrites its current position, but I think most operators (if not all) treat `.` as a special character so I don't think you can use any normal method

Comment: Thats weird, as when I tried to insert such field mongo thrown error: `JS Error: can't have . in field names [some.field]`, how youd did it in first place?

Comment: @PeterM older version of MongoDB, plus the constraint is driver dependant, it is not implemented in the server

Comment: Interesting behavior. I suggest you simply go ahead, delete and recreate documents, if your collection is not too big.